# Is this 'double +=' thread safe?

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

This line of code is being executed within a Parallel.For(...row => { code });

```
mechanismScores[row] += cellValue;
```

The array values and the cellValue are both of type **double**.  Is this thread safe or do I need to do something like...

```
Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref mechanismScores[row], 
    mechanismScores[row] + cellValue, mechanismScores[row]);
```

or another solution?

Comment: Neither of those are safe.  Two threads can read the same value and increment it.

Comment: Furthermore, what type is `mechanismScores`?

Comment: `Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref mechanismScores[row], mechanismScores[row] + cellValue, mechanismScores[row])` isn't safe: the function call could evaluate two different values for `mechanismScores[row]` for the second and third arguments if another thread were modifying it concurrently.

Comment: mechanismScores is of type double[]

Comment: After thinking about this further, I realise that mechanismScores[row] += cellValue; is fine.  As this is in a Parallel.For(... row =>, so no two threads will be updating a specific (the same element) mechanismScores[row] at the same time.

Answer (score 6):

If you have parallel loop where each iteration accesses different item in the array, and no other code is accessing the array at the same time, then your code is thread-safe.

If two iterations could access the same index in the array, you would need some sort of synchronization, either by using a `lock` or using `Interlocked.CompareExchange()` properly (as Michael Burr pointed out, your example is not safe).

Answer (score 0):

Whatever type mechanismScores is, it seems to be that is it an object, so a simple lock(mechanismScores) will do. If within the loop that same value can be changed in different contexts than it is not thread safe.

Comment: but bear in mind that locking mechanismScores (lock(mechanismScores)) will most likely erase any benefits of using the parallel.foreach in the first place.

Comment: That's not what the question asks.